# Node pagination in google datastore

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, pagination, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

I am having trouble doing the pagination with Google Datastore. I have a query which without the limit has a few hundred results. I would like to retrieve 5, send them back to the user, if the user wants more they would retrieve the next 5.

Following the docs I create the query:

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('ResultsKind').filter('name', 'bobby').limit(5).autoPaginate(false);
```

I then run this query to get the first 5 results:

```
datastore.runQuery(query, callback);
```

This is the callback function:

```
function callback(err, entities, nextQuery, apiResponse) {
    if (err) {
        // An error occurred while running the query.
        console.log('err ' + err);
        return;
    }

    if (nextQuery) {
        console.log('res = ' + entities);
        datastore.runQuery(nextQuery, callback);
    } else {
        // No more results exist.
        console.log('no more results');
        return;
    }
};
```

The problem is `res =` is being printed infinity times with no results in the console. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. What I would like to happen is.

```
1) I create the initial query.
2) I run the query.
3) I get the first 5 results.
4) I pass these results + the nextquery object to the user.
5) If the user wants more results the pass me back the nextQuery and I run this query and get the next 5 results and so on.
```

I have been looking at this doc:http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.30.2/datastore/query?method=autoPaginate.

How can I accomplish this simple pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within your callback, you are re-running the query directly after the `console.log`:

```
if (nextQuery) {
    console.log('res = ' + entities);
    datastore.runQuery(nextQuery, callback); // <-- Here
}
```

This is essentially doing the same thing as `autoPaginate(true)` does. Instead, you should remove that line, cache `nextQuery`, then run the same line that you removed to get the next batch of results when the user asks to.